# Can't install json 1.8 gem on Mac OS X 10.8.4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to to install my rails app on a second computer. But when I run `bundle install` I get an error with the json gem:

```
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/feuerball/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby extconf.rb 
/Users/feuerball/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby: invalid option -D  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/feuerball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/feuerball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing json (1.8.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

The computer runs Mac OS X 10.8.4 with Xcode 4.6.3 and the latest command line tools.

I installed the latest ruby using rvm:

```
$ rvm -v

rvm 1.21.2 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]

$ ruby -v
ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
$ gem -v
2.0.3
```

When I try to install the json gem using `gem install json` I get almost the same error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing json:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/feuerball/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/Users/feuerball/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby: invalid option -D  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)


Gem files will remain installed in /Users/feuerball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/json-1.8.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/feuerball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
```

Trying to install using `sudo` does not change anything.

I uninstalled and reinstalled homebrew, rvm, ruby & the command line tools but nothing helps.

**Update**

Contentent of `/Users/feuerball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generato‌​r/gem_make.out`:

```
/Users/feuerball/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/Users/feuerball/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby: invalid option -D  (-h will show valid options) (RuntimeError)
```

GCC Version:

```
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: i686-apple-darwin11
Configured with: /private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/src/configure --disable-checking --enable-werror --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2 --mandir=/share/man --enable-languages=c,objc,c++,obj-c++ --program-prefix=llvm- --program-transform-name=/^[cg][^.-]*$/s/$/-4.2/ --with-slibdir=/usr/lib --build=i686-apple-darwin11 --enable-llvm=/private/var/tmp/llvmgcc42/llvmgcc42-2336.11~182/dst-llvmCore/Developer/usr/local --program-prefix=i686-apple-darwin11- --host=x86_64-apple-darwin11 --target=i686-apple-darwin11 --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

**Update 2**

I did a fresh install of OS X, Xcode, Command Line Tools, Homebrew, rvm and Ruby. Ruby is now patch level 247 and the damn problem is still there. What a waste of time... If it is important: rvm installed json 1.7.7 together with ruby

**Update 3**

Seems that my machine fails on all native extensions. `gem install bcrypt-ruby` gives the same error message.

Comment: Could you gist the contents of /Users/feuerball/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/json-1.8.0/ext/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out

Comment: Since it contains only 2 lines, I inserted it into the original post.

Comment: This one has me at somewhat of a loss at the moment. I have exactly the same setup as you and the json gem installs without issue. rvm 1.21.2, gem 2.0.3, ruby 2.0.0p195 (2013-05-14 revision 40734) [x86_64-darwin12.3.0]. What's the output of gcc -v on your machine?

Comment: It's in the original post now, too.

Comment: Have you set ruby-2.0.0-p195 as your default ruby in rvm?

Comment: Yes I think so, because I directly installed it together with rvm.

Comment: The only thing that I can tink of right now to try installing json via ```:git => 'https://github.com/flori/json'``` and see if you get the same error.

Comment: Does not help. Seems that my machine is not able to build native gems. Now I get the same error when I try to install bcrypt-ruby.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was that my home folder is on a separate volume which contained a space in its name. Because of the space the second part of the name was interpreted as an option. The volumes name was something like `My Data` and thus I got the message`invalid option -D`.

I just renamed this volume and now everything installs fine.

Comment: same issues. basically bundle wasn't able to handle space in path name leads to wrong argument parsing. such as shame.

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to happen with Json versions 1.8.0 and 1.8.1 (Ruby 2.2.3) ... I was able to upgrade to 1.8.2 and 1.8.3 with no problems ... specifying those versions

```
gem 'json', '~> 1.8.2'
```

in my bundle got me around the problem.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, because it was not caused by the json gem.

Answer (score -1):

This seems to still be a bug...
https://github.com/flori/json/issues/163

Only caused with bundle.
Can you try the gem install json?
It might solve the problem after.

Comment: As I wrote `gem install json` does not work, too. Also `sudo` does not change anything.

Comment: Just FYI, NEVER use sudo with rvm.