# An error occurred while installing json (1.7.6), and Bundler cannot continue.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle

An error occurred while installing json (1.7.6), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.7.6'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: which os you are using?

Comment: Can you put more information about this? What dependencies are causing this?

Comment: the dependency is rdoc

Comment: https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/304 check this it will help u

Comment: gcc -v what it returns ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17322583/cant-install-json-1-8-gem-on-mac-os-x-10-8-4

Answer (score 1):

Might be your existing Ruby version does not support the gem. Use the gems that support by your Ruby version. If yours Ruby version is higher than 2.1.0 then degrade it to 2.1.0 then it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update your ruby installation . Which version it is ?

check it from terminal , try

```
ruby -v
```

Comment: does your OS has latest libs downloaded ? and command line tool ? you can download it . If it is downloaded then please go for new bundle up . if it still having some problem then try to see if it about permission denied or something like that or not . Check this https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer/issues/304 . and make sure you have new libs installed .